# In which case PERMISSION_DENIED error occurs in tableau SDK?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using tableau java SDK version 10.0 and I tried to publish the datasource in the sample project which is not belong to that user, I got [SERVER_ERROR](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/Java/com/tableausoftware/common/Result.html#SERVER_ERROR) instead of [PERMISSION_DENIED](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/Java/com/tableausoftware/common/Result.html#PERMISSION_DENIED) error

e.g Sample project belongs to sample users (user1, user2) but when I tried to publish the datasource as user3 then I got [SERVER_ERROR](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/Java/com/tableausoftware/common/Result.html#SERVER_ERROR) in this case user3 doesn't have permission to publish datasource in the sample project so it should return [PERMISSION_DENIED](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/Java/com/tableausoftware/common/Result.html#PERMISSION_DENIED) error but I got [SERVER_ERROR](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/Java/com/tableausoftware/common/Result.html#SERVER_ERROR)

In which case [PERMISSION_DENIED](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/Java/com/tableausoftware/common/Result.html#PERMISSION_DENIED) occurs?

Comment: Are you running as administrator?  Right click the app and run as admin

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your environment settings for the users mentioned.  But SQL or your database is I'd think a server.  So, the SERVER_ERROR is probably correct.  You may have to look deeper into the SERVER_ERROR properties to see.  The permission flag that you are looking for should be one of those values.